# WordPress - disable themes to use custom vuejs front-end app

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js

I'm developing a simple website that will use vuejs for the front end and wordpress to create dynamic contents. I have copied wordpress inside the `public` folder of my vue project inside a directory named `app`.I want to configure it to not use themes and to redirect each user that will open the app folder to the login page. I'm not a wordpress developer so I've done some researches and I've found the constant `WP_USE_THEMES`. It's not clear for me how it works, if I set it to false if I've understand, wordpress will not load and use themes right? If I follow this way, I will be able to use the REST api?How I will redirect users to login when they reach the app folder?

Answer (score 1):

You're still going to need an HTML template with a  mount point for the app, so it'd probably be easier just to create your own theme specifically for this and then just have the one index.php file in the theme directory.

Comment: also if I want. to run wp in headless mode?

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding the WP_USE_THEMES constant only affects the loop itself. You would need to create a custom Theme which  includes your app container.

Or you create a custom website that retrieves the data via the REST API.

See also: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_The_Loop

Comment: I don't want to use template tags of wordpress, as I said I have already a vuejs front end app that works fine and I will get the data from the REST api. I've readed some articles where it's not clear how to setup an headless version of wordpress, if I've caught how to setup it, I need to have a blank template to use. My doubt is how to redirect users to the login page but maybe it's not a great problem because if someone open the app folder will only see a blank page right?

Comment: Everyone is telling you, you still need some basic functionality inside a custom Wordpress theme todo this. Running a SPA still requires, surprise, a single page to mount it too. You’ll also need to use PHP to register any custom Ajax routes you may need for anything beyond the basic Wordpress API. All “headless” mean is that you’re using an API to populate the page and control routing rather than having PHP do it.